An affine and upper semicontinuous function is the limit of a sequence of continuous affine functions
In the book "An introduction to ergodic theory" by Peter Walters, there is a statement (P186) which indicates that "If $F:M(X,T) \to \mathbb{R}$ is affine and upper semicontinuous, then it is the limit of a decreasing sequence of continuous affine functions", where $X$ is a compact metric space, $T:X \to X$ is continuous, and $M(X,T)$ is the set of all $T$-invariant probability measures.
I know that a upper semicontinuous function is the limit of a decreasing sequence of continuous functions. But for an affine and upper semicontinous function, how to construct affine continuous functions to approximate it?
Any hints are welcome!

If an affine function is upper semicontinuous, it should be already lower semicontinuous (by multiplying the inequality with $-1$ and using linearity). Do I miss something?

Here we work in $M(X,T)$, all probability measures. Multiplying by $-1$ may not make sense. So I'm not clear how to show the continuity.
